# Power Automate - Sharepoint List "when an Item is created"-"The API operation 'GetOnNewItems' is missing "

Tags: list, power-automate, flow, trigger

I Created an approval workflow and for that my trigger was when an item is created , when i try to run the flow , I  get this Error message ,
[image: Problem in the Trigger of the flow " When an item is created]

Comment: Are you using any trigger condition inside trigger? Did you hide/remove Title column somehow from list?

Comment: Did you find a resolution? I am having the same issue